# How to show tooltip on mouseenter and hide on click with Tippy.js

Tags: javascript, tooltip, tippyjs

I am using [Tippy.js](https://atomiks.github.io). I would like to show the tooltip on mouseenter, but hide it on click.

This triggers a tooltip when you **click** on an element with `.tippy` and stays open until you click away.

```
tippy('.tippy', { trigger: 'click' });
```

This shows a tooltip when you **mouseenter** on an element with `.tippy` and hides when the mouse leaves the `.tippy` element.

```
tippy('.tippy', { trigger: 'mouseenter' });
```

I want a combination of both. Show tooltip on mouseenter, but leave it open until I click away.

I prefer to **not listen to the click events and mouseenter events and manually show it and hide it while using `{ trigger: 'manual' }`

In addition, could you please explain the `{custom}` trigger option. From the documentation:

> `{custom}` refers to the fact that you can have any event listener, but
>   it won't have the opposite "hide" event.

Can I use `{custom}` trigger for what I am looking for? How?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6):

Depending on the version, you can update the `trigger` using lifecycle hooks:

- v5: `setProps()` method
- v3-v4: `set()` method

Both work the same.

```
tippy('.tippy', {
  trigger: 'mouseenter',
  onShow(instance) {
    // v5
    instance.setProps({trigger: 'click'});
    // v3-v4
    // instance.set({trigger: 'click'});
  },
  onHide(instance) {
    // v5
    instance.setProps({trigger: 'mouseenter'});
    // v3-v4
    // instance.set({trigger: 'mouseenter'});
  }
});
```