# How do I hide TippyJS when element inside it is clicked?

Tags: tippyjs

I have to hide my tippy when an element inside it has been clicked (element is i.e. small images acting as links) but I have not been able to find any usefull scripts that works with my tippy.

I have i.e. tried these without luck:

[How to show tooltip on mouseenter and hide on click with Tippy.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45246206/how-to-show-tooltip-on-mouseenter-and-hide-on-click-with-tippy-js)

https://github.com/atomiks/tippyjs/issues/437

Can anyone help? :-)

**Here is my TippyJS :**

```js
tippy('#ReactionBar' + val, {
  a11y: true,
  role: 'tooltip',
  allowHTML: true,
  animation: 'perspective-extreme',
  appendTo: () => document.body,
  arrow: true,
  arrowType: 'sharp',
  boundary: 'HTMLElement',
  content: ReactionBarContent.get(0).outerHTML,
  delay: 0,
  offset: [0, 5],
  duration: [325, 275],
  hideOnClick: true,
  ignoreAttributes: false,
  inertia: false,
  interactive: true,
  interactiveBorder: 2,
  interactiveDebounce: 0,
  placement: 'top-end',
  popperOptions: {},
  showOnCreate: false,
  size: 'regular',
  target: '',
  theme: 'light',
  touch: true,
  trigger: 'mouseenter focus',
  triggerTarget: null,
  moveTransition: 'transform 0.2s ease-out',
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue and found using the onShown prop and instance.hide() method worked. I found the hideOnClick prop wasn't needed for this.

```
this.tippy = tippy(this.element, {
  // your other props
  interactive: true,
  trigger: 'click',
  triggerTarget: this.triggerTarget,
  onShown(instance) {
    document.querySelector('[data-tippy-root]').addEventListener('click', event => {
      instance.hide();
    })
  }
})
```

Comment: onShown ? is that a custom method or is that a prop from the library ? doesnt seem to work...

Comment: it's a prop that can run a method once the tooltip has rendered. https://atomiks.github.io/tippyjs/v6/all-props/#onshown